# Segmentation Fault in Vectors

Tags: c++, vector

So, I'm doing the famous "[The Blocks Problem"](http://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&category=3&page=show_problem&problem=37) from UVa Online Judge.

My approach is quite stupid, and that's because I wanted to play with vectors. So, I got vectors for pointers to each blocks in piles, and those vectors are stored in a vector called collection.

In order to find all the blocks, I have a vector called blockCollection, where pointers to all the blocks are stored inside.

The code has passed the samples provided. I will try to edit and provide comments later.

Full Source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Block
{
    int id;
    std::vector<Block*>* where;
};

int positionInVector(Block* b);

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    std::vector<std::vector<Block*>*> collection;
    std::vector<Block*> blockCollection;
    std::string command = "", command2 = "";
    int blockCount = 0, k = 0, A = 0, B = 0;

    while ( std::cin >> blockCount )
    {
        std::vector<Block*>* vectors = new std::vector<Block*>[blockCount];
        Block* blocks = new Block[blockCount];
        for ( k = 0 ; k < blockCount ; ++ k)
        {
            blocks[k].id = k;
            blocks[k].where = &vectors[k];
            vectors[k].push_back(&blocks[k]);
            blockCollection.push_back(&blocks[k]);
            collection.push_back(&vectors[k]);
        }
        std::cin >> std::ws;
        while ( std::cin >> command )
        {
            if ( command == "quit" ) break;
            std::cin >> A >> command2 >> B;
            Block* blockA = blockCollection[A];
            Block* blockB = blockCollection[B];
            std::vector<Block*>* vectorA = blockA -> where;
            std::vector<Block*>* vectorB = blockB -> where;

            //exception handle
            if ( A > blockCount || B > blockCount ) continue;
            if ( A == B ) continue;
            if ( vectorA == vectorB ) continue;

            if ( command == "move" )
            {
                //move anything on top of A to its original position
                int positionOfBlockAInVectorA = positionInVector(blockA);
                for ( int i = positionOfBlockAInVectorA + 1 ; i < vectorA -> size() ; ++ i )
                {
                    Block* blockToBeMoved = *(vectorA -> begin() + i);
                    std::vector<Block*>* destinationVector = collection[blockToBeMoved -> id];
                    blockToBeMoved -> where = destinationVector;
                    destinationVector -> push_back(blockToBeMoved);
                }
                vectorA -> erase(vectorA -> begin() + positionOfBlockAInVectorA + 1, vectorA -> end());
            }
            if ( command2 == "onto" )
            {
                //move anything on top of B to its original position
                int positionOfBlockBInVectorB = positionInVector(blockB);
                for ( int i = positionOfBlockBInVectorB + 1 ; i < vectorB -> size() ; ++ i )
                {
                    Block* blockToBeMoved = *(vectorB -> begin() + i);
                    std::vector<Block*>* destinationVector = collection[blockToBeMoved -> id];
                    blockToBeMoved -> where = destinationVector;
                    destinationVector -> push_back(blockToBeMoved);
                }
                if (positionOfBlockBInVectorB + 1 > vectorB -> size()) vectorA -> erase(vectorB -> begin() + positionOfBlockBInVectorB + 1, vectorB -> end());
            }
            if ( command == "move" )
            {
                //move block a to the pile containing block b
                vectorA -> pop_back();
                blockA -> where = vectorB;
                vectorB -> push_back(blockA);
            }
            else
            {
                //move block a and those on top of it to the pile containing block b
                std::vector<Block*> temperaryVector;
                int positionOfBlockAInVectorA = positionInVector(blockA);
                for ( int i = (int)vectorA -> size() - 1 ; i >= positionOfBlockAInVectorA ; -- i )
                {
                    temperaryVector.push_back(vectorA -> at(i));
                    vectorA -> erase(vectorA -> begin() + i);
                }
                for ( int i = (int)temperaryVector.size() - 1 ; i >= 0 ; -- i )
                {
                    temperaryVector[i] -> where = vectorB;
                    vectorB -> push_back(temperaryVector[i]);
                }
            }
        }

        for ( k = 0 ; k < blockCount ; ++ k )
        {
            std::vector<Block*>* vector = collection[k];
            std::cout << k << ":";
            if ( !vector -> empty() )
            {
                for ( int i = 0 ; i < vector -> size() ; ++ i )
                {
                    std::cout << " " << vector -> at(i) -> id;
                }
            }
            std::cout << std::endl;
        }
        delete [] blocks;
        delete [] vectors;
    }
    return 0;
}

int positionInVector(Block* block)
{
    std::vector<Block*> vector = *block -> where;
    for ( int i = 0 ; i < vector.size() ; ++ i )
    {
        if ( vector[i] == block ) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please post the stacktrace.

Comment: `A = (int)command[5] - 48; B = (int)command[12] - 48;` this sort of thing is just scary - who's to say that command even has 12 elements? Never mind that it's a "valid number".

Comment: Okay, you're right. That's stupid.

Comment: I'll edit the source so I wouldn't look toooo stupid.

Comment: Also, why on earth do you have a C-style array of `std::vector`s instead of `vector < vector >`?

Comment: @us2012 I guess I will be in hell if I show people that, I am just having fun with vectors.

Comment: @MatsPetersson Answer that! You're right, I got accepted.

Comment: Having fun is alright, although I would personally suggest to use the tools that you have correctly. Not only will that be at least as much fun, it will also train you good habits instead of bad ones. :P

Comment: I'll bite. Why do you need a pointer of vectors?

Comment: this is a very unusual construction: `std::vector<Block*>* vectors = new std::vector<Block*>[blockCount];` which you allocate and destroy in every loop. not so effective.

Comment: Yes, as I was accepted in one online judge, I received TLE in UVa. I see A LOT OF place that can be optimized. So, I'll maybe keep this updated somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work:

```
        A = (int)command[5] - 48;
        B = (int)command[12] - 48;
```

we are need to ensure that string is 5/12 characters long, and that there is a digit in those positions. The code should add checks for the length of input and validity of the digits in those places.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you add or delete a Block to your blockCollection, every pointer you hold to any Block in the collection may be invalidated.

I think that's all I need to say initially...

Comment: that's why I had a C-style array to create them initially. So they will remain there after.